# How to solve equations to get a close enough solution?

Tags: optimization, integer-programming

I have a linear equation with 3 variables and few linear constraints. How do I find `Integer` values for x, y and z such that the result is as close as possible to 0 (if exactly 0 is not possible)

```
-2x + 3y -5z = 0
given,
1 <= x <= 20
1 <= y <= 45
1 <= z <= 45
```

How do I convert this problem to Integer optimization problem? Is integer optimization even required?

Comment: This exact problem is small enough to brute force with a typical computer... But in general yes it is a (linear) [integer optimization problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming?wprov=sfla1). Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: To clarify, you can rewrite your objective as `min -2x+3y-5z` with the additional constraint that `-2x+3y-5z >= 0` which is still linear.

Comment: Or if you really need symmetry you can make your objective a quadratic `min (-2x+3y-5z)^2` and not add any additional constraints. That shouldn't be that much harder to solve, while being posed canonically.

Comment: For this particular problem it's really easy to find an answer just by putting positive values that solve the first equation. For example, since $y$ has coefficient $3$ and is opposite in sign from the other two terms, set $x=3$ and $z=3$; then $y=7$ gives an exact solution satisfying all constraints. And there are clearly several more exact solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Let $d$ be a nonnegative (continuous) variable. Minimize $d$ subject to $$-2x + 3y -5z \le d$$ and $$-d \le -2x + 3y -5z$$plus your domain constraints for the integer variables. The optimal value of $d$ will be the absolute value of your sum.